# project requirement

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

in my project i have a requirement like "**Set the  version to something like 0.0.0.0 if the method cannot get the version from the environment variable**"

and the coding where i need to look is like this array,,any one have idea about this on

```
string[] sade = new string[6];
 .
 .
 .
 .
  sade [5] = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\secon\secservice", "CurrentVersion", "0").ToString();)
;
```

any one have idea about coding required here

Comment: Are you talking about the version of the executable/dll? I thought that was fixed at build time with the AssemblyInfo provided to the build.

Comment: no version is taking from registry

Comment: AssemblyInfo.cs contains the version information for all .net Assemblies generated in visual studio. You can get it via reflection if the Assembly was loaded dynamically, or if you're only interested in the assembly that's executing you can get it this way: Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.

As for "... coding required here?" you'll need to be more specific. What -- specifically -- is it you want to know about the coding after you get the Assembly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
string[] sade = new string[6];
.
.
sade[5] = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\secon\secservice",    "CurrentVersion", "0");
if(sade[5] == null)
{
Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\secon\secservice",    "CurrentVersion", "0");
}
```

That will read the registry and check if it is already defined or not.

Comment: but i need to set in to 0.0.0.0

Comment: then change the "0" to "0.0.0.0"

Comment: @samoz, the Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\secon\secservice",    "CurrentVersion", "0"); line should be Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\secon\secservice",    "CurrentVersion", null); or you should compare sade[5] to "0"